# Access file paths inside package with NSURL

Tags: cocoa, path

I need to access a file "data" inside a package file content which is a project file used by another application.
The package could be at any place on any volume available.
SO in my app I ask the user to locate his project, therefore I obtain the project path. 
The structure inside the project file is always the same. So I would be able to locate the data file by appending the project "base" path with the path of its content directories until the data file.

But when I print the path get all directories fine but the package file name is withdrawn .
 If I print only the base path I get the correct path including the package at the end. It like its state cant appear in the middle of a path.

I have also tried`[NSBundle bundleWithPath]` but it returns `nul`. Though the finder does not consider the project file as a bundle but as a package file , it was just a last call in despair.

Here is the code :

```
` NSOpenPanel *getPath = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
NSArray* fileTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"logicx", nil];
[getPath setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[getPath setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[getPath setTreatsFilePackagesAsDirectories:NO];
[getPath setTitle:@"Select your Logic Pro X project file"];
[getPath setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
[getPath setCanCreateDirectories:YES];



NSInteger clicked = [getPath runModal];
if (clicked == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
    for (NSURL *basePath in [getPath URLs]){

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:(@"Alternatives/000/ProjectData") relativeToURL:basePath];
```

//"Alternatives/000/ProjectData" is the subpath of the package file

```
        NSURL *absURL = [url absoluteURL];


        NSLog(@"absURL = %@",absURL); `
```

The project package file name is : "Track Patch.logicx"

If I print `basePath` I get : `file:///Volumes/Media/Music/Logic/Track%20Patch.logicx`

If I print `absURL` which Is the requiered path , I get `absURL = file:///Volumes/Media/Music/Logic/Alternatives/000/ProjectData`

the package Track Patch has been ditched here.

If I print the url (pointer) I get this `absURL = Alternatives/000/ProjectData -- file:///Volumes/Media/Music/Logic/Track%20Patch.logicx`

So the path is inverted which make me think there is a problem with the `[NSURL URLWithString: relativeToURL:basePath];` function. what the `--` means by the way?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am really confused about what you are asking. Is "Alternatives/000/ProjectData" the subpath you want to look at inside the package?

Comment: Yes exaclty, sorry if I was not clrear enough, I am going to edit the post to make this clear. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `URLWithString:relativeToURL:` says that you need a trailing slash for it to treat is a directory.

> "you can construct a URL for the file by providing the folder’s URL
>   as the base path (with a trailing slash)"

You can solve this by using the `URLByAppendingPathComponent` method instead, like so:

```
NSURL *url = [basePath URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Alternatives/000/ProjectData"];
```

> "If the original URL does not end with a forward slash and
>   pathComponent does not begin with a forward slash, a forward slash is
>   inserted between the two parts of the returned URL, unless the
>   original URL is the empty string."

[NSURL Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/URLByAppendingPathComponent:)

Comment: Thank you Justin, that fixed it ;)  And thanks again for taking the time to explain why my function was not appropriate!